# Is a colon a legal first character in an XML tag name?

Tags: xml, specifications, well-formed

According to the [W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags), start tag-names have the definition:

```
STag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
```

..where `Name` is:

```
Name ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | ...
```

..(n.b., states that a colon can appear as the first character) suggesting the following is a valid XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><:doc></:doc>
```

..but any parser I try this in shows the colon as a formatting error.

Also, under Appendices B (though now a depreciated part of the document) it explicitly states:

```
Characters ':' and '_' are allowed as name-start characters.
```

..and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><_doc></_doc>
```

..is accepted by the XML parsers I've tried.

So, is a colon a valid first character in a tag-name, and the parsers I'm using are wrong, or am I reading the specification wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, at the base XML level, colon (`:`) is allowed as a name-start character.  The BNF rules you cite clearly specify this.

However, the [W3C XML Recommendation is clear](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn) that colons should not be used except for namespaces purposes:

> **Note:**
>
> The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [[XML Names]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#xml-names) assigns a
>   meaning to names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors
>   should not use the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes,
>   but XML processors must accept the colon as a name character.

And the [XML Namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) BNF rules for tags are based on [QName](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-QName), which allow for colon in a name only as a separated between `Prefix` and `LocalPart`:

> ```
> QName          ::= PrefixedName | UnprefixedName
> PrefixedName   ::= Prefix ':' LocalPart
> UnprefixedName ::= LocalPart
> Prefix         ::= NCName
> LocalPart      ::= NCName
> NCName         ::= Name - (Char* ':' Char*) /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */
> ```

One might ask why colon wasn't disallowed in `NameStartChar` from the beginning.  If we're lucky, C. M. Sperberg-McQueen may offer an authoritative explanation.  However, I suspect it's a matter of an evolving notion of how namespaces were expected to be designed.

The [first published working draft in 1996](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xml-961114) of the W3C XML Recommendation had a definition of [`STag`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xml-961114#sec3.1) which [did not allow colon](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xml-961114#NT-Name):

> ```
> STag  ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
> Name  ::= (Letter | '-') (Letter | Digit | '-' | '.')*
> ```

By 1998, colons were allowed in [`Name`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#NT-Name),

> ```
> Name  ::= (Letter | '_' | ':') (NameChar)*
> ```

and an [earlier form](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#sec-common-syn) of the admonition about colon use read:

> **Note:** The colon character within XML names is reserved for experimentation with name spaces. Its meaning is expected to be
>   standardized at some future point, at which point those documents
>   using the colon for experimental purposes may need to be updated.
>   (There is no guarantee that any name-space mechanism adopted for XML
>   will in fact use the colon as a name-space delimiter.) In practice,
>   this means that authors should not use the colon in XML names except
>   as part of name-space experiments, but that XML processors should
>   accept the colon as a name character.

The need was anticipated but the precise form perhaps was not yet known when colon was first introduced to tag names.

Answer (score 3):

They are allowed in non-namespace-aware XML but they are not allowed in namespace-aware XML. More specifically, the base XML recommendation allows them but the Namespaces recommendation prohibits them. Very few people nowadays use non-namespace-aware XML (and I'm not sure what parsers support it) so it's best to assume they aren't allowed.