# How to add xs:type as an attribute name in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to insert an element  with xs:type inside it like an attribute, while transforming my xml file using an xslt.

The output needed is in the following format

> `<Region xs:type="tRegion"/>`

But in xslt file it shows the compile time error **"Namespace prefix 'xs' is not defined"**. But I don't want to define a namespace here. Instead add a colon.

Kindly suggest a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT works on namespace well-formed XML (both for input and output) and is itself namespace well-formed XML so having an attribute name with a colon without declaring a namespace for the prefix before the colon is not possible because
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-qualnames mandates:

> The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the qualified name,
>   and MUST be associated with a namespace URI reference in a namespace
>   declaration

Comment: +1 See also [Is a colon a legal first character in an XML tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40445735/290085)

Answer (score 0):

The output `<Region xs:type="tRegion"/>` can be obtained by adding the following definition for 'xs'

> xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Thanks.

Comment: That, of course, is the right way to eliminate the error, but you should accept Martin's answer because it's correct given that you said you *don't want to define a namespace here. Instead add a colon.*