# Unable to load XML with "colon" attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

We are developing some DevOps module which reads/parses/cleanup some markup files and other artifacts. There is no need of validations to be performed against existing.

As part of above, we are trying to read few existing vue.js templates which have attribute prefixes as just "colon".  It is a valid syntax according to vue.js.  Unfortunately, we are not able to load that markup using c#.

I have following markup, which is valid according to vue.js:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <AppCodeDropDownList :activityCode="activity.ActivityCode" 
        :activitySubcode="activity.ActivitySubCode" :mode="mode" 
        v-on:activity-code-selection="onActivityCodeSelection" 
        v-on:activity-subcode-selection="onActivitySubCodeSelection">
    </AppCodeDropDownList>
</div>
```

I used XML reader as following:

```
XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
xrs.CheckCharacters = false;
xrs.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
xrs.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
xrs.IgnoreComments = true;
xrs.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
xrs.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sourceFile, xrs))
{
    while (reader.Read())...
```

It throws an error

> Name cannot begin with the ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A'.

In simple terms, imagine that I would like to read the above markup, do some "process" on each of the nodes, and write back similar kind of markup to some other file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe vue.js is wrong about this?

Comment: It's not valid XML. Looks like a null namespace or something. You would at least need a preprocessor.

Comment: I mean you could swap ‚:‘ with something like ‚a:‘ (where ‚a‘ is unique), then do the processing and strip the a from the XML. But this is really a quick and dirty approach

Comment: It's not XML, don't try to parse it as such. One option is to parse as HTML though, [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) should load this fine and allow you to manipulate it.

Comment: Several users have suggested that this is not valid XML, but I'm not so sure about that... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445735/is-a-colon-a-legal-first-character-in-an-xml-tag-name

Comment: @rutter - do read the answer under that question.

Comment: @bommelding The one that says XML parsers should accept colons in names? Yeah, I did.

Comment: You should read that a little better (past the first paragraph).